# Show CoreTemp Remote Monitoring Temperature on Webpage

Tags: php, ajax, curl, get, monitoring

I would like to show what CoreTemp is monitoring on my personal website. The CoreTemp reports in what I can tell JSON format. However, it appears that when I do a cron or a GET requests, nothing ever shows from the CoreTemp page. I think this may have to do with it must return 5 results before displaying it on the local webpage at http://localhost:5200/.

Example output from CoreTemp Monitoring page:

```
{"CpuInfo":
    {"uiLoad":[2,3],
    "uiTjMax":[100],
    "uiCoreCnt":2,
    "uiCPUCnt":1,
    "fTemp":[49,48],
    "fVID":1.065918,
    "fCPUSpeed":3292.04028,
    "fFSBSpeed":99.7588,
    "fMultiplier":33,
    "CPUName":"Intel Core i5 4310M (Haswell) ",
    "ucFahrenheit":0,
    "ucDeltaToTjMax":0,
    "ucTdpSupported":1,
    "ucPowerSupported":1,
    "uiStructVersion":2,
    "uiTdp":[37],
    "fPower":[5.889584],
    "fMultipliers":[33,33]},
    "MemoryInfo":{
        "TotalPhys":16282,
        "FreePhys":8473,
        "TotalPage":17304,
        "FreePage":8473,
        "TotalVirtual":8388608,
        "FreeVirtual":8388003,
        "FreeExtendedVirtual":1,
        "MemoryLoad":47}}
```

Again, I'm getting stuck even to have *any* data show up from a simple GET or curl request from php.

Simple php code:

```
<?php
$exe = curl_init();
curl_setopt($exe, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:5200/");
curl_setopt($exe, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($exe, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$raw = curl_exec($exe);
curl_close($exe);
echo $raw;
```

What am I missing or is this a problem with the Monitoring plug in itself?

Comment: [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) is your friend.

Comment: Adding that returns an infinite spinning wheel and nothing ever shows on screen. I think that it has to do with the way CoreTemp queries the system.